# Class Object appears under if and else statement in for-loop Why?

Tags: python, class, for-loop, if-statement

Why does the class object with option="first" appear in the list `btest` and the list `ctest`?

I have this problem with a larger piece of code so I wrote this smaller piece to understand better how this if/else statements work in a for-loop with list of class objects. But I still don't understand it.

```
class test:
   def __init__(self,option,place):
       self.option=option
       self.place=place

   def __repr__(self):
       return("option:"+self.option+"\npalce:"+self.place)


optionlist=["first","second","thrid","fourth"]
placelist=["switzerland","germany","thailand","italy"]
testlist=[]

item=0
while item <len(optionlist):
   testl=test(optionlist[item],placelist[item])
   testlist.append(testl)
   item+=1

btest=[]
ctest=[]

for x in testlist:
    if x.option=="first":
       btest.append(x)
       print("here")       
    if x.option=="second": 
        print("here2") 

        # If I delete this 2nd if statement the ctest list
        # doesn't contain a object with option="first", but if I
        # leave it it does. Why?
    else:
        ctest.append(x)
        print("no")

print("btest:",btest)
print("ctest:",ctest)
```

If I let this code run *without the 2nd `if` statement it gives me the following output:

```
here
no
no
no
btest: [option:first
palce:switzerland]
ctest: [option:second
palce:germany, option:thrid
palce:thailand, option:fourth
palce:italy]
```

Well that's also what I would expect, but why does it give the following output if I let it run *with the 2nd if statement:

```
here
no
here2
no
no
btest: [option:first
palce:switzerland]
ctest: [option:first
palce:switzerland, option:thrid
palce:thailand, option:fourth
palce:italy]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you coded it to do it like this:

```
if x.option=="first": 
   btest.append(x)               # when x.option == "first" add to btest
   print("here")       

if x.option=="second": 
    print("here2") 
else:
    ctest.append(x)              # when x.option NOT "second" add to ctest
    print("no")                  #      x.option == "first" is NOT second - so added
```

You can change it to if:  elif:  else: ... then `second` would never be added to anything because it only `print`s

Answer (score 0):

Because it's two different  `if` statement.
Looks like you need to use `if/elif/else`:

```
    if x.option=="first":
       btest.append(x)
       print("here")       
    elif x.option=="second": 
        print("here2") 

        # If I delete this 2nd if statement the ctest list
        # doesn't contain a object with option="first", but if I
        # leave it it does. Why?
    else:
        ctest.append(x)
        print("no")
```